# Make Scrollbar thumb looks like circle CSS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

How to make scrollbar thumb looks like circle. I need something like on image.[image: Round thimb of scroll bar]

Suggested question is not the same because it not about **circle thumb**.

Maybe there is JavaScript or jQuery way to solve it?

Again! I needed circle **thum**, not a scrollBar **rectangle**.

Comment: css has no control over that. by definition, the scrollbar is outside the browser's web rendering area.

Comment: If you have to do some extra stuff when scrolling, i'd recommend iscroll (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) It gives you, besides styling, a lot of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good JS solution [here](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)!